# Do Kraken in Valheim resurface in the same place?

Tags: valheim

I've only found a Kraken twice in my current world; each time, after mining it a bit, it sank beneath the waves.

Will the Kraken eventually resurface in the spots where I originally found it? If so, what's the timer?

Or am I doomed to just sail around the world in hopes of finding a new random spawn?

Comment: They seem to be extremely common, at least in my map...

Comment: Not on mine, they aren’t.

Answer (score 4):

These are known as "Leviathans" within the game, and colloquially, the term Kraken is also used. They have a chance to sink every time you strike one of the barnacles, and **once they go under water, they never come back**.

It's best to be prepared with several players spread out across the shell to coordinate mining all at once, and it's wise to bring a stamina potion and tasty mead, in case you end up in the water and have to swim back to your boat.

You can get more information on the [wiki](https://valheim.fandom.com/wiki/Leviathan)!